# SqlConnection, password is trimmed

Tags: asp.net, sql, passwords, sqlconnection

I am developing an ASP.NET web application and I use the following  connection string to authenticate:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(UserConnectionString())
```

The issue is that if I have for example the password : "pass123" and I enter "    pass123" or "pass123   ", the uses authenticates, and will be logged in. The password is trimmed, any suggestions to block this?

Comment: yes, don't use leading and/or trailing spaces in the password, it will cause troubles..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the password in the connection string in either single- or double- quotations marks, as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectionstring.aspx) to preserve leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: My pleasure - glad to have been of assistance.